# Will already having a masters degree make it harder to get funding for a second masters in Europe?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, funding, europe, second-degree

If a person who already has M.Sc degree (from the university outside of Europe) wants to enter European university for another M.Sc degree, would having M.Sc degree be a hindrance for getting a scholarship or other kind of funding?

Comment: No.Most of the programs do not care.rather its a plus point for you.

Comment: Is your previous masters in the same field of study or a different field?

Comment: I think scholarships for a Masters are rather rare in continental Europe, could you clarify in which country you plan to apply for scholarships?

Comment: @ff524 previous M.Sc degree is "Information Systems and Technology". Later, I would like to study Computer Science. Is  it a different field?

Comment: Based on my experience, asking this question about a "European university" is too broad. Some countries require tuition, some don't. Some universities have available seats, some don't. Some places a second degree will probably help, others hurt. I would suggest finding the exact university you wish to apply for and then contact e.g. their student councilling service.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the exact degree you already hold and when and where you earned it, and what you want to study at this European school, and why. For admissions purposes you should explain in your SOP why you need another degree in the same field.